# How can I insert a value of money with currency symbol into SQL? and it displays out of range value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

here is my problem lol. How can solve it out?

I have to shows it like below:

[image]

Comment: You need to create a column for currency and another for amount

Answer (score 1):

You ask how ? I think it is not a very **good idea** to put a symbol($) in the money column, converting it to varchar. Because it will create problems when you will manipulate the column in future e.g applying discount etc.

My suggestion is to put a new column **named currency** that contains that contains desired currency value e.g **USD** .

Comment: what datatype is ? would it be like currency varchar() , valuation numeric()?

Comment: Yes that would be my suggestion , value should be stored as numeric, While currency should be stored separately in varchar or char.

Comment: Well decimal is a datatype capable of holding decimal values like 2.33. so is numeric , no major difference . It is reliable for storing money. But  do not use float if that option is available because it has some accuracy issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Option One  - LEAST RECOMMENDED**

Since you are mixing a string an numeric datatypes, you need to alter the datatype to varchar. Here some good info about datatypes

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp

Altering the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `Paintings` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Valuation` `Valuation` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL;
```

**Option Two**

Of if you really want to store the value as a decimal,  just add the string in the query by concatenating the symbol in the query:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('$',valuation) as 'valuation_nice' FROM Painting
```

**option Three**

A third option would be to save the currency symbol in another field `symbol`

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(symbol, valuation) as 'valuation_nice' FROM Painting
```

Comment: do you mean i need to change the datatype from decimal to varchar? Ive tried like this: valuation varchar(20). insert: '$150000.50'... it seems wired????

Comment: Either 3 of the options i've suggested will work. Its up to you what you go with. If the symbol always stays the same the second option will be fine. but if it could change then i would store it in a separate field as @gul suggested

Comment: would it be like ? currency varchar() ? I cant insert the money into decimal tho.................it says out of range value...

Comment: Dude seriously, have you read peoples answers. We have all spelled out the same thing that if you want to put that string into a field it much be a varchar. But we have also recommended better options

Comment: yes, I cant insert the info into numeric(15,2), it still says out of range value

Comment: Ive given you the exact query in my post to change it to a varchar